# Prevent VPN Disconnection message OSX

Tags: applescript, sleep-wake, vpn

When my computer wakes from sleep, it tries to reconnect to my VPN network before the Wifi connection is fully established. The result is that nearly every time I get this message, "You were disconnected because the PPP server is not responding. Try reconnecting."

Is there a way to disable this message or prevent OS X from reconnection on sleep (automatically of course).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
sudo nano /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist
```

Find the vpn connection you want the disconnect-dialog to go away and set the key “DisconnectOnSleep” to 1 (instead of 0)

Comment: Worked for me after a reboot.